# Does Leaflet have a "geopositioning mode"?

Tags: leaflet

I use the Leaflet plug-in "Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated.js" to use its L.imageOverlay.rotated(...) thing in order to overlay certain map pieces in various places on top of the normal map.

It does this by taking an image and having me tell it its top-left, top-right and bottom-left coordinates to figure out how to rotate, tilt and stretch/squeeze it properly.

It took me a very long time to figure these coordinates out by hand. For this reason, I'm looking for some sort of "geopositioning mode", perhaps enabled by this extension, which would simply let me click three times on the map to tell it where these points go. That would be so simple for the developers to do and would help so much. It's such an obvious thing to do that I strongly suspect it's already implemented and ready.

Is there such a "mode"? If not, how am I expected to find the positions without spending so much time and trial-and-error as I did for the first overlay map image?

Added: I should also clarify that the image should be shown in this mode so that you can re-adjust the points and watch in real time as the image bends/warps, to get it just right.

Comment: "_It's such an obvious thing to do that I strongly suspect it's already implemented and ready_" => no, it is a [whole topic in itself](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georeferencing), and it is called [_Georeferencing_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeferencing)

Comment: The plugin [demo](http://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/demo.html) might be doing something in the lines of what you describe, so you could simply adapt [its code](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.ImageOverlay.Rotated/blob/gh-pages/demo.html).

Comment: Yes! That demo is exactly like I imagined it! That's how I wanna do it on my map! Sadly, I don't understand its code, so this will be a really annoying nut to crack...

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. I did figure it out after all. Works now. The only problem I have left is actually getting the positions of those markers. How can I do that?

Comment: Nevermind that question too. It's all cleared up now. Thanks.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: why is there no bottom-right "corner"?

Comment: Good job in figuring out how to make it work! Please consider sharing your solution as an answer to this question, so that other people with the same need as you can find it out quicker.

Answer (score 0):

you can develop a modul for this problem.

1. find minimum 4 point on raster map.
2. click on tilemap for 4 points
3. than find different slope and distance same 2 points.
4. maybe you must rotate and use affine transformation.